# Finite group with isomorphic normal subgroups and non-isomorphic quotients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

I know it is possible for a group $G$ to have normal subgroups $H, K$, such that $H\cong K$ but $G/H\not\cong G/K$, but I couldn't think of any examples with $G$ finite. What is an illustrative example?

Comment: Other readers might like to note that the "correct" hypothesis to ensure that $G/H \cong G/K$ is that not only is there an isomorphism of $H$ to $K$, but one that extends to an automorphism of $G$.  In other words, there should be an automorphism of $G$ that maps $H$ onto $K$.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Take $G = \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, $H$ generated by $(0,1)$, $K$ generated by $(2,0)$.  Then $H \cong K \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ but $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}_4$ while $G/K \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's a good one. Clearly my group theory is a little rusty...

Comment: Nice example!

Comment: @Nate: This will also work if our $H = \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ right?

Comment: @Chandrasekhar: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You can think of $H$ as $\{0\} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \subset \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ if you want...

Comment: @NateEldredge: thats precisely what i wanted.