# Give an example of a group $G$ with $N,M \triangleleft G$ such that $N \cong M$, but $G/M \not \cong G/N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to find  an example of a group $G$ with $N$ and $M$ normal subgroups such that $N \cong M$, but $G/M \not \cong G/N$.

Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151911/g-is-a-group-h-cong-k-then-is-g-h-cong-g-k?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

$N=G=\mathbb Z$, $M=2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ with subgroups generated by $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ respectively.