# Counterexamples to particular questions in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples

Let $G$ be a finite group with normal subgroups $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$. Find counter examples to the following statements

1) If $N_{1}\cong N_{2}$ then $G/N_{1}\cong G/N_{2}$

2) If $G/N_{1}\cong G/N_{2}$ then $N_{1}\cong N_{2}$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Or try harder to solve it yourself. There is an abelian group of order 8 which provides a counterexample to both 1 and 2.

Comment: @YACP: It’s not a particularly easy thing to search for; I doubt that I’d have managed to find a relevant question without your strong suggestion that one was there to be found to keep me trying different searches. You really ought to have supplied a pointer.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7720/finite-group-with-isomorphic-normal-subgroups-and-non-isomorphic-quotients).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Take $G=\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. This group provides a basis for counter-examples to both of your statements.