# $G/N\cong G/N'$ implies $N\cong N'$ for the normal subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

We have normal subgroups $ N$ and $ N'$ of a group $ G $. Is the following statement correct?

$G/N\cong G/N'\Leftrightarrow N\cong N'$.

$\Leftarrow $ is trivial.

$\Rightarrow:$ I don't know how to start. Or should I search for counter examples?

I would be pleased, if someone could give a hint.

Comment: Neither direction is true, so you should probably think a bit more about the "trivial".

Comment: Also, I am certain this is a duplicate, but I can't find to what right now.

Comment: Related: [Finite group with isomorphic normal subgroups and non-isomorphic quotients?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7720) and [Isomorphic quotients by isomorphic normal subgroups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40881) and several linked questions.

Comment: An example to what @TobiasKildetoft said. Take $$G=C_4\times C_2=\langle x\rangle\times \langle y \rangle.$$ Now take $N_1=\langle y \rangle$ and $N_2=\langle x^2\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for the links @barto. I could not find them, when I wrote the article. For the "trivial" case, I only thought of equality and not isomorphy. Great mistake! Sorry!