# On the isomorphism between two finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K,H$ be two normal subgroups of $G$ such that $N \cong K$. Then can we say that $G/N \cong G/K$?

Comment: you should at least try something before dumping questions on us. Questions such as this one are likely to be closed.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7720

Comment: This possible duplicate was found [here](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7BG%7D%7BN%7D%5C%20%5Ccong%5C%20%5Cfrac%7BG%7D%7BM%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: thank you very much dear Watson

Answer (score 3):

With $G = Z_4 \times Z_2$, consider subgroups of order two.

Comment: @Hana: Check for yourself.

Comment: Bolton, please avoid posting a comment as an answer.

Comment: @Ittay, it's not a comment, it's a hint.